# RexExp in javascript dont match a number inside a string

Tags: javascript, regex

Im learning Regular Expresions in Javascript and there is a thing that i dont understand.

The following regexp should match any string from a to z but if I add a number it says that is correct

```
var patron = /[a-zA-Z]/;
var regex = new RegExp(patron);
        var v= "hello word 512";

        if(v.match(regex))
        {
            //should not match but it does
        }else
        {
            objInput.style.color = "red";
        }
```

And them i tried this:

```
 var patron = /[a-zA-Z\D]/;
var regex = new RegExp(patron);
        var v= "hello word 512";

        if(v.match(regex))
        {
            //should not match but still dont work
        }else
        {
            objInput.style.color = "red";
        }
```

And also, parentheses are not being match

```
 var patron = /[a-zA-Z\"\']/;
    var regex = new RegExp(patron);
            var v= "hello word 512";

        if(v.match(regex))
        {
            //it match whenever the double quoute it followed by the single quoute'
        }else
        {
            objInput.style.color = "red";
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

About the first example you provided, your regex `/[a-zA-Z]/` checks for any character in the input string. Since it finds `h` in your input string, it returns true.
What you need to do is place start and end anchors, `^` and `$` in your regex. New regex would look like this:

```
/^[a-zA-Z]+$/
```

You can make changes to all you regex accordingly.

To match parentheses, you need to escape them with a backslash. `\(` would match `(`, and `\)` would match `)`.

Comment: i just tested it using `/^[a-zA-Z]+$/.test("asda55456")`, and it returned false. So its working fine for me. Check if you have placed the anchors that i mentioned correctly.

Comment: why when i add a \S to /^[a-zA-Z\S]+$/ match when there is a number? if i add a number it says that mathc

Comment: ok now i understand why lol, the ^ and the $ solve the white space

Comment: no, `^` and `$` specify the start and end. if the regex is `/^ali$/` and the input is `ali`, it would match. But if the input is `ali shah`, it won't match.

Comment: and if the input has a white space it wont match neither

Comment: Yeah, to match a white space, we need to add `\s`. So the regex would look like `/^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/`. Now it would match any number of white spaces.

Answer (score 2):

You should match the **whole string**, using the **^** (matches the beginning of the string) and **$** (matches the end of the string) operators, for example:

```
/^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/.test("any string followed by numbers! 555") // will return false
```

This will not allow anything else than `a-z` chars and spaces in your string.

Comment: You are missing a quantifier after the character class, so it would match only a one letter string.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning the OP would need to cater for spaces based on their given example

Comment: still dont match,i used this var patron = /^[a-zA-Z]$/;
  
  if(/^[a-zA-Z]$/.test("SDFDD"))
  {
   objInput.style.color="green";
  }else
  {
   objInput.style.color = "red";
  }

Comment: Thanks for the tips guys, I've improved my anwser.

Comment: This is a quantifier operator. It will match at least one char. Take a look at here for more quantifiers: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Answer (score 0):

the match function seeks for at least ONE match in your case this is 1st symbol which is a char.
if you want ONLY chars then use /[a-zA-Z]/.test("your string")